# Is root activity the current first activity in the stack or the activity specified as launch activity in manifest?

Tags: android

Is root activity the current first activity in the stack or the activity specified as launch activity in manifest?

Support application P starts activity A at launch. Then A starts B and finish itself, and then B starts C. Now the stack contains B and C, with B the first in the stack.

Can I say B is the root activity, or A is still the root activity.

I want to make clear of it because I am trying to understanding the definition of clearTaskOnLaunch:

android:clearTaskOnLaunch
    Whether or not all activities will be removed from the task, except for the root activity,   whenever it is re-launched from the home screen — "true" if the task is always stripped down to its root activity, and "false" if not.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little uncertain of how you are launching Activity B from A. If A is being removed from the stack, and Activity C is launched from B - and if `clearTaskOnLaunch` is set to `true` - if the user presses HOME from Activity C, and then returns to your application - Activity B will be displayed, as C will have been removed from the stack.